# Why is this returning null?

Tags: java

The assignment is to read the maximum value of the ArrayList and return it, and if it's 0 or empty return and print null. But when I run it, the output is null for negative numbers when it should only return null for 0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int addNum = -1;

    //User inputs numbers for the list until they input 0
    while (addNum != 0) {

        addNum = input.nextInt();
        list.add(addNum);

    }

    //Sends it to the method to check for the biggest number
    Integer i = max(list);

    //It returns null if it's negative for some reason
    if (i == null) {
        System.out.println((String) null);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The greatest number is " + i);
    }
}

public static Integer max(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    Integer i = Collections.max(list);

    //Even though the if statement says only if it is equal to 0
    if (i == 0) {
        return (null);
    } else {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Sample Run

```
-12
-151
-1221
-2121
-61
-42
0
null
```

Comment: did you check if elements are being added to your list ?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is here :

```
//User inputs numbers for the list until they input 0
while (addNum != 0) {

    addNum = input.nextInt();
    list.add(addNum);

}
```

When you get the 0, you also add it to the list. Lexically, 0 is greater than all negative integers, so your `max()` function always returns null.

You can fix it like this(this is a hackjob, there are better ways, you probably want to consider how you're doing things, it's pretty redundant currently):

```
//User inputs numbers for the list until they input 0
while (addNum != 0) {

    addNum = input.nextInt();
    if(addNum == 0)
        break;
    list.add(addNum);

}
```

Comment: I'd use `addNum = input.nextInt(); while(addNum !=0) { list.add(addNum); addNum = input.nextInt(); }` instead.

Comment: @YvesDubois works, OP's implementation is already redundant, I wouldn't even use the while loop

Answer (score 0):

The error is because If user enters 0, it is added to the list and in the next iteration you break the while loop. You need to fix it.